# How to write a junit test for double linked list's insertion in between operation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a double linked list in which i can perform various functions but I want to write JUnit tests to test those functionalities.
I have written unit tests for testing operations like inserting node at end and head, but how to write a test for the **insertion in between** operation?

Thank you :)

Here is the my linked list and Test class

DoubleLinkedList.java

```
public class DoubleLinkedList {

  Node head;

  public void add(int data) {
      Node newNode = new Node(data);
      if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
      } else {
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = current;
      }
  }

  public void print() {
      Node current = head;
      while (current != null) {
          System.out.print(current.data);
          if (current.next != null)
              System.out.print(" -> ");
          current = current.next;
      }
      System.out.println();
  }

  public int size() {
      int size = 0;
      Node current = head;
      while (current != null) {
          size++;
          current = current.next;
      }
      return size;
  }

  public void addIntoHead(int data) {
      Node newNode = new Node(data);

     if (head == null) {
          head = newNode;
      } else {
          head.prev = newNode;
          newNode.next = head;
          head = newNode;
      }
  }

  public int returnHead() {
      return head.data;
  }

  public void addInMiddle(int prevData, int data) {
      Node current = head;
      while (current != null) {
        if (current.data != prevData) {
            current = current.next;
        } else{
            break;
        }
      }
      Node newNode = new Node(data);
      newNode.next = current.next;
      current.next.prev = newNode;
      newNode.prev = current;
      current.next = newNode;
  }
```

}

DoubleLinkedListTest.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class DoubleLinkedListTest {

  private DoubleLinkedList dll;

  @org.junit.Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
      dll = new DoubleLinkedList();
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldBeAbleToCreateANewNode() throws Exception {
      int initialSizeBeforeAdd = dll.size();

      dll.add(1);
      dll.add(2);

      assertEquals(initialSizeBeforeAdd+2,dll.size());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldAbleToAddIntoHead() throws Exception {
      dll.add(1);
      dll.add(2);

      dll.addIntoHead(0);

      assertEquals(0,dll.returnHead());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldAbleToAddDataInMiddle() throws Exception {
      dll.add(1);
      dll.add(2);
      dll.add(4);
      int size = dll.size();

      dll.addInMiddle(2,3);

    //what should be the assertion here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check also the other unit tests. I think for the test `shouldAbleToAddIntoHead` the assert is wrong. You are adding 1,2 and 12. Why do you expect `returnHead` to return 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is: in order for a component to be useful, it needs "reasonable" interfaces. Your main problem with your current list is: it doesn't provide good means to access its content!

It is nice that you can ask for the size() of your list - but how do you think a user should retrieve each node in your list?!

In other words: step back, and look at a list from the perspective of a "client" that would instantiate such a list to store data. Such a users needs the methods you provided so far; but wouldn't the user want some way to iterate all elements in the list in an easy, reliable way?!

For example, you could implement a method that returns some sort of *iterator* that allows you to go forward/backward within the list. And as soon as you have such a feature in place, writing your missing test becomes really simple:

1. You create a list with a certain layout, maybe 1-2-4-5
2. You insert a new node 3 between 2-4
3. You iterate the new list, and expect that it contains 1-2-3-4-5

And of course, you have a double linked list, you should test iterating in "both directions".

Long story short: when you do your initial design; don't get too hung up on the details upfront. Instead, try to figure the most important "use cases" first; in other words: "try to get the 'whole picture' (versus focusing on too low-level details up-front).

Comment: Thank you sir, that not only solved my problem but also taught me how to write better programs which are testable and hence more maintainable.

Comment: You are very welcome. Always glad to hear such things.

Comment: @GhostCat If you are writing the `iterator()` method then `add()` is required to test the `iterator()` method. So without testing the `iterator()` is it fine to use it for testing `add()`.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the tests for insertion "inbetween" or in the middle is not so difficult. You can

- Create a list with prefined length and entries
- Use your method under test to insert a new item to the list.
- Use at least an assert to check that the new item was inserted at the correct position, i.e. `assertEquals(5,dll.get(3))`. `get(int x)` is currently not implemented, but you can add it easily and make it package-private.

You should also test for different situations, e.g. insertion in an empty list.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I already have them but i have not posted them here.